# Simplify Scala loop to one line

Tags: scala

How do I simplify this loop to some function like foreach or map or other thing with Scala? I want to put hitsArray inside that filter shipList.filter.

```
val hitsArray: Array[String] = T.split(" ");
for (hit <- hitsArray) {
  shipSize = shipList.length
  shipList = shipList.filter(!_.equalsIgnoreCase(hit))
}
if (shipList.length == 0) {
  shipSunk = shipSunk + 1
} else if (shipList.length < shipSize) {
  shipHit = shipHit + 1
}
```

Comment: `val hitsArray: Array[String] = T.split(" "); for (hit <- hitsArray) { shipSize = shipList.length; shipList = shipList.filter(!_.equalsIgnoreCase(hit)) }; if (shipList.length == 0) { shipSunk = shipSunk + 1 } else if (shipList.length < shipSize) { shipHit = shipHit + 1 };` There you go! One line. Although I don't understand what this obsession with "making it one line" is. Do you think my version is in any way superior to yours, just because it is one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be fair, I don't understand why you are calling `shipSize = shipList.length` as you don't use it anywhere.

```
T.split(" ").foreach{ hit => 
  shipList = shipList.filter(!_.equalsIgnoreCase(hit)) 
}
```

which gets you to where you want to go. I've made it 3 lines because you want to emphasize you're working via side effect in that `foreach`. That said, I don't see any advantage to making it a one-liner. What you had before was perfectly readable.

Comment: thank you. I edited to show why I need shipSize. I could do with your example.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe?

```
shipList.filter(ship => T.split(" ").forall(!_.equalsIgnoreCase(ship)))
```

Although cleaner if `shipList` is already all lower case:

```
shipList.filterNot(T.split(" ").map(_.toLowerCase) contains _)
```

Or if your `T` is large, move it outside the loop:

```
val hits = T.split(" ").map(_.toLowerCase)
shipList.filterNot(hits contains _)
```

Comment: I think you need to do `shipList.map(_.toLowerCase)...` too in you last example.